# Online Malware Scanner Without Installation

Tags: malware

I would like to scan a usb flash drive for malware so I was wondering if there any reputable and reliable online malware scanner that doesn't need installation. I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Installing software means putting it on your computer so you can run it. You have to install it to run it on your computer if you want it to scan your computer.

There are plenty of reputable online scanners, but you have to send the file to them to be scanned. Such as this one: https://www.virustotal.com/

Or, Windows 10's built in scanner apparently does a fair job at scanning things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB drive, you have to plug it into something to get the files. The question is fairly broad, as you don't specify whether you want to use a Windows PC as the host, Mac, or Linux. Another assumption could be made that you do not currently have any sort of Anti-virus software installed on a machine that you could scan the USB drive.

If you use a PC, you could have ClamWin portable on another folder, or even a second USB drive that you can run to test.
http://portableapps.com/apps/security/
Booting with Windows Defender Offline might ease your mind too.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17466/windows-defender-offline-help-protect-my-pc

Comment: I will edit my question.